# PHP: get all occurences of string in long string at once

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a very long string and I want to get the data from it. In the string there is a similar part repeated many times. For example:

```
...
Price: 1,540
Ref No.: x24345543             &nbsp;
&nbsp;
Shape: square              
Size: 12.91           &nbsp;
...
Price: 2,222
Ref No.: ydeft             &nbsp;
&nbsp;
Shape: triangle  maybe_something_else_which_is_not_needed        
Size: 11.11       
...
```

I know I can use combination of `strpos` and `substr` but I guess I would need to use `strpos` twice and `substr` once to get just one item and then again using functions each on the whole string.

Is there any faster solution to achieve this?

Comment: use regular expression?

Comment: [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/preg_match_all)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with the following regex:

```
~^((?!&nbsp;|\.+)[^:]+):\s*(\S+)~
# ^ - anchor to the start
# (?!) - negative lookahead - no &nbsp; or lines of dots
# match everything except a colon and capture it to group 1
# match a colon, some whitspaces
# capture everything that is not a whitespace into group 2
```

See a demo for this [approach on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/zZ3tN7/1).
Translated to `PHP` code, this would be:

```
$regex = '~^((?!&nbsp;|\.+)[^:]+):\s*(\S+)~gm';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    // improve the world with it
    echo "Category: " . $match[1] . ", value: " . $match[2] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks. the input strings are like Price: 1,540
                                    Ref No.: x24345543             &nbsp;
                                    &nbsp;
                                    Shape: square                                    &nbsp;
                                    Size: 12.91                                    &nbsp;

Comment: @koubin: Please edit your original question and put some sample strings in there.

Comment: thank you. your example works great. is there a way to get rid of additional "&nbsp" (an maybe even spaces at the line beginning) like in this example? https://regex101.com/r/zZ3tN7/2

Comment: I probably need just the data, so I found this part of your regex would be enough: ":\s*(\S+)". thank you very much for your help